# Excel, How to add a box which marks another box complete when filled?

Tags: vba, excel

Quite a hard questions to write.

I need to be able to have a blank box which you can enter a number, which will return a "Yes" or "No" in a field on another sheet.

So I want to be able to enter value in a box on sheet 1, which then finds the corresponding number on sheet 2 and marks the delivered column as a yes.

I can do that, but i want to be able to re-enter a number in the box without deleting the "Yes" on sheet two?

Comment: To clarify: If you enter "42" on sheet 1, there is a column of number on sheet 2 containing "42", that gets marked with a "Yes". Then, if you change the number on sheet 1 to "2001", the Sheet 2 "42" goes back to "No", and the Sheet 2 "2001" goes to "Yes"?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. I want to be able to once the information is set on sheet two, lock that data, so on sheet 1 i can re-enter a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the cells where you want "Yes" to appear, do something like:

`=If(A1 = Sheet1!$A$1,"Yes","")` to mark the cell as "Yes" if its corrosponding cell in the list matches the Sheet1 value.
Then, after entering a number in Sheet1, run the following macro, which you should probably connect to a button or keyboard shortcut:

```
Sub LockYes()
Dim rCell as Range
Dim rYes as Range
Set rYes = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B") 'This should be the range where you expect "Yes" to appear. Also, for performance reasons, restricting to your actual used range (like "B2:B1000") would be beneficial. There are other places on SO that could help you make this dynamic as well...

For Each rCell in rYes
    If rCell.Value = "Yes" Then rCell.Value = rCell.Value 'This will remove the formula and leave the value as a static "Yes"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If it helps, please mark as accepted. :-) Also, I edited my answer slightly to address a possible performance concern.

Comment: Can =If(A1 = Sheet1!$A$1,"Yes","") have a vlookup incorporated so it searches for the number in sheet 1, and if it finds it mark box as yes, then i can run the button to lock cell, so i can then enter next number?

Comment: Yes. As long as the value on Sheet2 is "Yes" (no matter how it gets there), the macro will remove the formula and set the value to a static "Yes".

Comment: Fantastic, this really helped not hitting my head against my desk! It works!